# Issue with object initialization from initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, list-initialization

I have the following code:

```
    class A {
        public: 
        A(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>){}
    };

    auto x = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    auto y = std::make_shared<int>(1);

    auto list = {x, y};
    auto res = std::make_shared<A>({x, y});
```

In the example if I pass to res variable list it compiles, otherwise as in the case of using initializer list directly it fails http://ideone.com/8jYsDY

I guess it has to do with the way type deduction works when initializer_list are involved. If this is standard conformant some reference would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) deduces its second template parameter from the arguments to the function call. A braced-init-list is not an expression, and as such, has no type. Hence template argument deduction cannot deduce a type from it.

From *§14.8.2.5/5 [temp.deduct.type]*

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>     — `...`
>     — A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter does not have `std::initializer_list` or reference to possibly cv-qualified `std::initializer_list` type. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>  template<class T> void g(T);
>  g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

`auto`, however, is a special case that is allowed to deduce `std::initializer_list<T>` from a braced-init-list.

*§7.1.6.4/7 [dcl.spec.auto]*

> `...` **Otherwise, obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto`** with either a new invented type template parameter U or, **if the initializer is a *braced-init-list*, with `std::initializer_list<U>`. Deduce a value for `U` using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call** (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a function template parameter type and the initializer is the corresponding argument. If the deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, the type deduced for the variable or return type is obtained by substituting the deduced `U` into `P`. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
>  auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
>  auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

In your example, the variable `list` has the type `initializer_list<shared_ptr<int>>`, and when you pass it to `make_shared`, a `vector` can be constructed from it, which is then used to direct-initialize the `A` instance.

Other options are to construct a `vector`

```
auto res = std::make_shared<A>(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>{x, y});
```

construct an `A`, which will then be moved

```
auto res = std::make_shared<A>(A{{x, y}});
```

or specify the template parameters for `make_shared` explicitly

```
auto res = std::make_shared<A, std::initializer_list<std::shared_ptr<int>>>({x, y});
```